# How to find non-string indices in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, indices

There is a array like

```
a = ['string', '1', '2', 'string2', '4', 'string5', '5' ...]
```

how can I find non-string indices like

```
[1,2,4,6 ...]
```

It doesn't work If I use

```
isinstance(a, str)
```

Answer (score 5):

If your `list` has `integers` and strings, you can use [`isnumeric`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric) with [`List Comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
In [843]: a = ['string', '1', '2', 'string2', '4', 'string5', '5']

In [847]: ans = [a.index(i) for i in a if i.isnumeric()]

In [848]: ans
Out[848]: [1, 2, 4, 6]
```

OR, using `enumerate` as per @MushifAliNawaz's comment:

```
In [874]: ans = [c for c,i in enumerate(a) if i.isnumeric()]

In [875]: ans
Out[875]: [1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Instead of `a.index(i)`, `enumerate()` can be used it would be much faster and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `loop` and check each element in array:

```
>>> a = ['string', '1', '2', 'string1', '3', 'string2', '3.0', '2.5']
>>> results = []
>>> for v in a:
...     try:
...             value = int(v)
...     except ValueError:
...             try:
...                     value = float(v)
...             except ValueError:
...                     continue
...     results.append(value)
...
>>> results
[1, 2, 3, 3.0, 2.5]
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but likely downvoted as this approach is very inefficient and does not create a new list as required.

Comment: The OP's list contains numbers as strings. Even though looping is the key here, you'll have to instead check if it can be converted to a number (eg with `.isnumeric`) not if it is an int.

Comment: Re Using `.isnumeric`, this way do not cover the case number is float type.

Answer (score 1):

```
[i for i, x in zip(range(len(a)), a) if not isinstance(x,str)]
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary complexity?

Comment: Using enumerate() would shorten this a bit. Then again, it still would not work, because all the elements in the list are strings.